# I want to access Zammand (which runs on nginx) from the mobile app but i get the standard "welcome to nginx"?

Tags: nginx

Like the title says it, I need to configure my server to that it is reachable via the IP. I'm just asking where i can redirect/reroute it in the config?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i found out that in the nginx config you have to add an ip and an DNS Entry and it works :)